# How to bold DataRow in c#?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I added new `DataRow` in my `DataSet` like this:

```
if(ds.Tables["Report"].Rows.Count != 0) 
{
    DataRow row = ds.Tables["Report"].NewRow();
    row["NAME"] = "Sum:";
    row["NAME_RJ"] = String.Empty;
    row["SUM1"] = sum1;
    row["SUM2"] = sum2;
    ds.Tables["Report"].Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Any idea how to bold this `DataRow`?

Comment: What? You have to use reporting tools! You can't "bold" row in datatable!

Comment: You can bold a row on a `GridView` for webforms and a row on `DataGridView` for winforms but you cannot bold a `DataRow` for a `DataTable`. Before you ask for an example, try it first then post another question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do bold to `DataRow` in `DataTable`. You need to do this where you are binding `DataTable` like `GridViews`, `DataLists` etc.

Comment: You can do this in Grid views by Handle the CellFormatting event of the DataGridView and apply a bold style to the font if the cell belongs to a row

Comment: Ok, tnx for reply.